# Bundling Python program with a native binary

Tags: python

Simple question:
I have a python program which launches an executable.
The launcher uses `optparse` module to setup the run and lauch the binary through shell.

Is it possible to bundle the laucher and the binary into a single package?
Platform of interest is Linux.

Answer (score 2):

using pyinstaller for example you could add the executable file as a resource file, it extracts the resources to a temp folder, from there you can access your resource files as you want